# Error en la carga de archivos

Tags: web, https

Al subir un sitio web, con sus funciones, estilos, etc.(Ya completo con todos su archivos a UAT) me aparece un error de que esta bloqueando ciertos archivos js como el main.

Y con la herrramienta de desarrollador me aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo claro si es un problema con el certificado o es el cache, o los requerimientos. Tiene muchos requerimientos como ubicación, micrófono, cámara, ubicación, etc.

También quisiera saber como es que le puedo quitar algunos requerimientos.

Podrían apoyarme  por favor de que podría hacer yo con mi sitio web?

Comment: Por casualidad ¿tienes algún(os) formulario(s) cuyo atributo `action` comienza con `http` en lugar de `https`?

Comment: Si ya lo cheque, muchas gracias, lo encontre y estaba en false, lo cambie a true y cargo la pagina correctamente. Gracias!!